# How to pair users together on iOS using Twilio Programmable Video SDK

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, twilio

Problem: I am trying to pair two users together in Twilio's Programmable Video API for iOS on a single call using a server generated Twilio Access Token.

Steps taken:

I have setup the web server that generates tokens successfully on node.js and deployed to Heroku. Each time the connect button is pressed on the client app, the token URL (web server URL) is visited, token is generated and client app uses token to create room.

This creates a problem because each user connecting generates a new token for each time pressing connect - so no two users can ever connect together.

How can I create a token that relies on the room and not the user / a token that is generated each time a room is made, and not each time a user connects?

For additional background, I leveraged the Twilio Quickstart app for Swift iOS and swapped the localhost URL for the my Heroku hosted server.  The first code shown is from the server.  The second is from the client-side Swift app.

```
function tokenGenerator(identity, room) {

  const token = new AccessToken(
    process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );

  // Assign identity to the token
  token.identity = identity;

  // Grant the access token Twilio Video capabilities
  const grant = new VideoGrant();
  grant.room = room;
  token.addGrant(grant);

  // Serialize the token to a JWT string
  return token.toJwt();
}
```

---

```
do {
   accessToken = try TokenUtils.fetchToken(url: tokenUrl)
   print(accessToken)
   } catch {
   let message = "Failed to fetch access token"
   logMessage(messageText: message)
   return
   }
```

Each grant.room uses a room.  The Twilio Programmable Video API default behavior is, if the room is blank, create a randomly generated room id (called sid in the docs). Note that, in my app, even when I specify a room across two different machines, I cannot connect because there are two separate access tokens.  When this happens, one user is disconnected and the other connects.  What steps can be taken to fix this use case? -- Thank you all

Comment: I got a response from Twilio support about this.  He replied that I am facing this issue since I am trying to pass the same token using the exact same room and identity.  The room needs to be the same and the identity needs to be unique for each user.  I'll try tinkering with the access token code later tonight to make this work.